# STM32 DMA Receives UART Data in Wrong Order After First Time

Tags: stm32, uart, dma

I have a project using the STM32L010F4 that receives six bytes of data via the UART. Once received, it should then send on an ACK to a different device. The RX data has a known SOF and EOF byte. I am using the DMA to receive the data. After restarting the project, the first time I get data it is in the correct order: the first byte is the SOF, then four bytes of data, then the EOF byte. However, subsequent receptions have the EOF byte first, then the SOF byte, then the four data bytes. I am clearing the RX buffer between reads, so I don't think this can be a case of leftover data.

```
/* Private user code -------------------------------------------*/
uint8_t RX_Data[6] = {0};
uint8_t ACK_Data[3] = {0x01, 0x30, 0x0D};
uint8_t RX_Data_Rdy = 0;
uint8_t TX_Data_Pending = 0;

/**
   * @brief  The application entry point.
   * @retval int
*/
int main(void)
{
   /* MCU Configuration-----------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  MX_LPUART1_UART_Init();

  /* Infinite loop */
  while (1)
  {
      if(RX_Data_Rdy != 1)
      {
          uint8_t Result = HAL_UART_Receive_DMA (&huart2, RX_Data, 6);
      }

      if(TX_Data_Pending)
      {
          HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA(&hlpuart1, ACK_Data, 3);
      }
  }
}

void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
     RX_Data_Rdy = 1;
    TX_Data_Pending = 1;
}

void HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
    TX_Data_Pending = 0;
    RX_Data_Rdy = 0;
    memset(RX_Data, 0, 6);
}
```

Comment: You are reading the return value into a variable `Result`, but then not checking it. You may find it is returning `HAL_BUSY`, because you're actually just calling `HAL_UART_Receive_DMA()` in a tight loop.

Comment: Note that if you have nothing else to do while waiting for the reception to complete, then it would be much simpler to just call `HAL_UART_Receive()`. Adding interrupts or DMA just needlessly complicates things.

Comment: You have not provided a minimal, reproducible example. How is `RX_Data_Rdy` initialized, if at all? How does `RX_Data_Rdy` become `1`, if ever?

Comment: "*I am clearing the RX buffer between reads, so I don't think this can be a case of leftover data*" -- Good example of using a presumption (or an unverified assumption) to prematurely dismiss the most likely cause. Or you are (improperly) expecting/relying on the read operations to perform message delimiting for you.

Comment: @pmacfarlane I posted an incomplete code sample. I have updated: subsequent data RX is only done if the callback has been called, signalling the end of transmission.

Comment: I don't think your logic is correct. Subsequent RX is done _repeatedly_ in a tight loop whenever `RX_Data_Ready == 0`. Is there are reason you are using DMA here? You seem to be deliberately making life difficult for yourself.

Comment: @pmacfarlane I have tried to reduce my application down to the simplest version possible here for clarity. There is data processing that needs to be performed after data is received. To your other question: RX_Data_Ready is only cleared to zero once the callback has been called (and in this case, some otjer data processing is completed).

Comment: Yes indeed. You do know that `HAL_UART_Receive_DMA()` returns straight away, before any characters have been received, right? So your main loop will spin round and round, calling `HAL_UART_Receive_DMA()` many times before your callback is called. The same thing happens when you are in "transmit" mode, you'll be spinning around and around the main loop calling `HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA()` many, many times.

Comment: @pmacfarlane Right, but I was hopimg that's what my flags were doing: only calling "Receive_DMA" if the data ready flag is NOT set (meaning data either hasn't been received or has been received and processed).

Comment: Both of your flags are either both zero or both one. So you might as well just have one flag. From there, you'll see that you always call either the receive or transmit function, _every time_ around the main loop. There's no option to do nothing  because you're waiting for the hardware to complete.

Comment: "*but am continuing to have an issue with a sprurious extra byte*" -- Why do you assume that any read operation by your code is synchronized with the actual reception of messages? If you really don't know when a message will arrive, then the system (i.e. a device driver) has to be *always* "reading" and buffering that data (for later processing). "*There is data processing that needs to be performed after data is received.*" -- And then your (unposted) code has an opportunity to loose (not read) incoming bytes (of the next message)! **Do you ever check the UART status for receive overrun?**

Comment: "*I have tried to reduce my application down to the simplest version possible*" -- You've reduced the code to present a bogus example. The "*data processing that needs to be performed*" is salient to the problem. You neglect to mention what or why or how often this message is transmitted to your STM32. Without synchronization or buffering, your code cannot just read, process, and then try to read again without the possibility of losing a message. Reading a "next" message starting with the last byte of the previous message is exactly the type of symptom expected with a receive overrun.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is broken because it only really has two states: receiving, in which case you are calling `HAL_UART_Receive_DMA()` repeatedly in a loop, and transmitting, in which case you are calling `HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA()` repeatedly in a loop.

By far the easiest solution would be to forget about DMA and interrupts, and just use the regular polling routines, e.g.:

```
while (1)
{
    HAL_StatusTypeDef result;

    result = HAL_UART_Receive(&huart2, RX_Data, 6, 1000); // 1000ms timeout
    if (result != HAL_OK)
    {
        // Handle error or timeout
    }

    result = HAL_UART_Transmit(&hlpuart1, ACK_Data, 3, 1000);
    if (result != HAL_OK)
    {
        // Handle error or timeout
    }
}
```

If you are absolutely determined that you must use DMA and interrupts, you really need more than two states to tell you what you are currently doing. It could be something like:

```
enum state_e {
    STATE_READY_TO_RECEIVE,
    STATE_RECEIVING,
    STATE_READY_TO_SEND,
    STATE_SENDING
};

volatile enum state_e state = STATE_READY_TO_RECEIVE;

int main(void)
{
    // Other initialisation stuff here

    while (1)
    {
        HAL_StatusTypedef result;

        switch(state)
        {
        case STATE_READY_TO_RECEIVE:
            result = HAL_UART_Receive_DMA (&huart2, RX_Data, 6);
            // check result for errors
            state = STATE_RECEIVING;
            break;

        case STATE_READY_TO_SEND:
            result = HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA(&hlpuart1, ACK_Data, 3);
            // check result for errors
            state = STATE_SENDING;
            break;

        case STATE_RECEIVING:
        case STATE_SENDING:
            // Nothing to do, waiting for the hardware
            break;

        default:
            // handle bad state error
            break;
        }
    }
}

void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
    if (state == STATE_RECEIVING)
    {
        state = STATE_READY_TO_SEND;
    }
    else
    {
        // error - state machine broken
    }
}

void HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
    if (state == STATE_SENDING)
    {
        state = STATE_READY_TO_RECEIVE;
    }
    else
    {
        // error - state machine broken
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried implementing this (thank you!), but am continuing to have an issue with a sprurious extra byte getting loaded into RX_Data[0] AFTER the RXCplt callback. When I first hit the callback, I get all six bytes in the order I expect. But subsequent callbacks seem to load new data starting at RX_Data[0], and I can't figure out why.

Comment: It sounds like you're either starting a new reception before processing the data, or you have the DMA configured in circular buffer mode.

Comment: The DMA is definitely in normal (non-circular) mode. And since the new reception can only start after the RXCplt callback has been called, doesn't that mean the previous RX must already be done?

Comment: @nobby If you're still having problems, and your code has changed enough to render all the comments and my answer on this question irrelevant, I'd suggest posting a new question with your new code.

Comment: This does address issues with the (minimal) code posted, but does not solve the actual problem because the OP seems to have omitted salient details such as how often do the messages arrive and how much processing is performed between reads. If a second message arrives at the UART but is unread, then that would leave its last byte as valid data and become the first byte of the "next" message transferred by DMA.

Comment: @sawdust Agreed - they need a better buffering scheme if data can come in back-to-back. It could be as simple as a buffer twice as long, and use the half-complete interrupt, if processing doesn't take too long. There's not enough information to know what they need though.